# Regular expression to change function into another function in netbeans

Tags: jquery, regex, netbeans

The project that I am working with wants to upgrade from jquery 1.6.4 to 1.9.1...who can I use Regular Expression to Change:

```
"$(".btnPrint").live("click", function() {"
```

into this

```
"$('body').delegate(".btnPrint", "click", function() {"
```

with Netbeans...

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `.delegate` either.  Use `.on`.

```
/\$\((["'])(.*?)\1)\.live\((["'])(.*?)\3/$("body").on("\2", "\4"
```

Answer (score 0):

Anyways, got the answer for the community..

In netbeans:

Put the following in "Find What" input.

`\$((["'][^"']+["'])).live(["']click["']`

And the following in "Replace With" input.

`\$('body').on("click", $1`